# Angular 2 Typescript Compilation Errors

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-services

When I start my node lite server and compile for the first time I come up against this error

```
 app/components/Projects/list/ProjectListComponent.ts(34,22): error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Object'.
```

so this is inside my projects component, basically I have a service doing a get request for some json and pulling it in and in my controller I have this function which waits for the service to successfully subscribe then it will activate my jQuery masonry plugin, doing it this way is the only way to ensure the masonry loads correctly

```
    this.project.subscribe(() => {

        console.log('Projects Initialized');
        //alert('podog');

            setTimeout(function() {
                jQuery('.wrapper').masonry({
                    columnWidth: 5,
                    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
                    isFitWidth: true,
                    isAnimated: true,
                    gutter: 15,
                    animationOptions: {
                        duration: 300,
                        queue: false
                    }
                })
            }, 10);    
    });
```

The strange this is when I remove the subscribe function wrapping the timeout and start the compiler and lite server everything runs fine which to be expected, stranger still is when I readd the code while everything is already running then it compiles it no problem.. Im pretty new to angular 2 but I am aware about defning variable explicitly and I have tried this

```
 declare var subscribe: any;
```

to no avail and im guessing its because its actually a function of sorts.. any help greatly appreciated.

just in case its necessary heres what my services file looks like

```
        import {Http, Headers, Response} from "@angular/http"
        import {Injectable} from "@angular/core"
        import {IProjectsMain} from "../interfaces/IProjectsMain"
        import 'rxjs/Rx';
        import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
        import {Observer} from 'rxjs/Observer';
        import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';
        import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

        @Injectable()
        export class ProjectsMainApi {

            apiUrl: string = "http://www.url.io/api/projects";

            headers: Headers = new Headers;

            project$: Observable<IProjectsMain[]>;

            private _ProjectsMainObserver: Observer<IProjectsMain[]>;

            private _dataStore: {

                project: IProjectsMain[]

            };

            constructor(private _http: Http) {

                this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

                this.headers.append('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');

                //this.project$ = new Observable(observer => this._ProjectsMainObserver = observer).share();
                this.project$ = new Observable<IProjectsMain[]>(observer => this._ProjectsMainObserver = observer).share();
                this._dataStore = { project: [] };
            }

            public getProjectsMain() {

                this._http.get(this.apiUrl).map(response => response.json()).subscribe(data => {

                    this._dataStore.project = data.project;

                    this._ProjectsMainObserver.next(this._dataStore.project);

                }, error => console.log('Could not load projects.'),
                    () => "done");

            }

        }
```

and my tsconfig.json

```
  {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "removeComments": false,
      "noImplicitAny": false
    },
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "typings/main",
      "typings/main.d.ts"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Your observable's name is `project$` but you subscribe to `this.project`, why is that so ?

Comment: because its assigned to it here this.project = this._projectsmainapi.project$;